# Como alterar dll de Referencia com o aplicativo em execução?

Tags: c#, referência

Estou com um projeto onde preciso utilizar uma referencia com versões diferentes em uma unica execução, exemplo:

Trocar a referencia System.Drawing versão 2.0.0 para a System.Drawing versão 1.0.0

É possivel fazer isso?

Comment: Por que isso é necessário? Descreva melhor o seu problema, pois talvez existam outras formas de resolver e que podem não ter nada a ver com a versão da `System.Drawing`

Comment: fiquei curioso pra saber o motivo de querer isso, pra mim não faz sentido

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Exato... porque até dá para fazer copiando, renomeando e utilizando alias... Mas não consigo enxergar algum sentido nisso.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo acho que nem assim... mas vou aguardar o motivo da coisa

Comment: Estou lidando com integração de sistema, onde as versões mais antigas do sistema utiliza dll com uma versão mais antiga e quando o programa estiver fazendo calculos em sistemas mais recentes, ele precisa mudar a referencia dessa dll antiga para uma versão mais nova. Basicamente eu não consigo usar essa dll recente em um sistema antigo, por isso tenho que alterar ela. E preciso fazer isso na mesma execução. Pois vou fazer calculos em sistemas de versões diferentes com a mesma dll (com versões diferentes).

Comment: É possível carregar uma dll dinamicamente, mas não é possível referenciar.
Se você já adicionou essa referência à seu projeto, ela não pode ser mudada e o programa utilizará essa referência. No seu caso você não poderá referenciar essa dll e depois carregar as que precisa dinamicamente utilizando `Assembly.Load(path)`. Depois você pode usar os métodos da dll utilizando reflection.

Answer (score 0):

É possível através de uma invocação dinâmica do assembly:

```
// caminho da DLL antiga
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("caminho");

// tipo da classe desejada
dynamic instancia = assembly.CreateInstance("tipo");

// chamar o método que está procurando ou fazer o que precisar com a variável
instancia.MetodoDesejado();
```